# How to extract subtitles from MKV file split in segments with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I have an MKV file of an aniem that uses some external segments in this way:

1. beginning of video
2. opening / intro (external file #1)
3. middle of video
4. ending / outro (external file #2)
5. preview

I would like to extract the subs as they would show up in the video to use on a better version of the video.

How can I do that with FFMPEG?